# micro-ros agent displays usage (and won't start) with valid arguments

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the tutorial First micro-ROS Application on Linux and I can't seem to get the microros agent to start. At the command `ros2 run micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent udp4 --port 8888` I keep getting the Usage popping up as though I have not entered the correct argument. I have also tried with the other valid arguments with no luck. Not sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360494/micro-ros-agent-displays-usage-(and-won%27t-start)-with-valid-arguments/) by [usermayne_](https://answers.ros.org/users/58705/usermayne_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-08-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good morning,

I'm afraid this is related with a new feature we have been starting to roll regarding the CLI interface. It is working when compiling the Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent, but not for micro_ros_agent; we are already working on fixing it.
If you could open an issue on GitHub regarding this problem, it would be highly appreciated: https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/issues

Regards,
Jose
(SW Engineer at eProsima)

---

Originally posted by [jamoralp](https://answers.ros.org/users/58828/jamoralp/) with karma: 26 on 2020-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jamoralp](https://answers.ros.org/users/58828/jamoralp/) on 2020-08-31**:
See related PR solving this issue: https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent/pull/183
Compiling `micro_ros_agent` now using `micro_ros_setup` helper scripts should produce a successful agent compilation. Regarding the `micro_ros_agent` Docker, please wait until it is correctly deployed by dockerhub: https://hub.docker.com/repository/registry-1.docker.io/microros/micro-ros-agent/builds/803c4940-673c-4ef4-9dea-d189c572e793

Thanks again for reporting the issue!